# Is Sharepoint 2007 Output Cache Better on a Publishing Site's Pages Library?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, cache

We were advised by an adviser to move the landing page of our main portal from:

> start.company.com/**default.aspx**

to:

> start.company.com/**pages/MainPage.aspx**

The claim is that the "*output cache applies only to the Pages library of a publishing site*".
This is an internal site, and all users are authenticated. The site is set as the home page of most users, and we would like the front page to be as fast as possible.
Is output caching really disabled in this page? If not, it is better on the *pages* library?

Answer (score 2):

I can't find any reference to this only applying to pages stored in the Pages library in [Microsoft's documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc298466(office.12).aspx).  What Microsoft says is:

> Output caching can only be used on a site or site collection if the Office SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature is activated for the site collection and the Office SharePoint Server Publishing feature is activated for the site.

Content in other pages is still stored in SQL Server, so unless Microsoft specifically designed it this way (anything seems possible with Sharepoint), I don't see why it would matter.  I'd also be interested to know if it does.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't find anything concrete either. As you've said, anything's possible, but it does seem there's some correlation between output caching an publishing... (Also, congratulations on reaching 1K!)

Comment: Hey - thanks for the upvote bringing me to 1k.  I probably didn't deserve it, as I didn't really answer the question with much certainty.  Hopefully someone else will come along with more specific knowledge, or time to test...